# How to specify which program to run in one solution?

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

I just got into c# and downloaded Rider, created a solution and stuff.
I created to projects to run two programs (bc in one project can be only one main entry point), and after I launch my program it only executes first one. I can't figure it out how to specify executing each program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project and select "Set startup project" before pressing the Start Button.
Either, you can choose the right project with the dropdown near the start button.

Comment: Yeah, thanks dude, helped me out)